# Issue running the RESTler image from docker hub (proc/1/stat error related)

Tags: docker, build-automation, fuzzy, fuzzing

About the official **Restler** image on Docker Hub, that is available with this command:

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/restlerfuzzer/restler`

[image: docker images]

I tried to run the container with `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/restlerfuzzer/restler`, and then i navigate to `/RESTler/restler` folder and made `chmod -x ./Restler.exe`.

Then a tried to run the fuzzing tool however give me an error about proc/1/stat.

```
/RESTler/restler # ./Restler.exe
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilGetPpid:1244: Failed to parse: /proc/1/stat, content: 1 (sh) S 0 1 1 34816 11 4194560 462 165 0 0 0 5 0 0 20 0 1 0 199236 1712128 273 18446744073709551615 94302295961600 94302296599409 140723708314976 0 0 0 0 2637828 65538 1 0 0 17 6 0 0 0 0 0 94302296741904 94302296756272 94302324797440 140723708321510 140723708321518 140723708321518 140723708321776 0
```

Does anyone know about this issue?

Thanks